# 2 pictures not entirely side by side

Tags: graphics, floats, diagrams

I am using the following command to get two pictures side by side but my problem is that sometimes they are not.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./bla}
\caption{Management of cultural differences}
\label{fig:management cultural}
\end{minipage}
%\hspace{0.5cm}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{./bla}
\caption{Employees leaving}
\label{fig:employee leaving}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

What do I mean? Normally the would be exactly side by side -> O O but sometimes they are offset: one picture is "higher" than the other and the are not aligned anymore...

Comment: you probably want to use `[t]` on the minipage so they align on the images at the top rather than on the possibly vaying caption. Also put `\label` _in_ the caption not after it if you are using `[b]`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Could you make that an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Or alternatively, you could try something like this, using the overpic package to annotate both images, using only one caption for both.

[image: Overpic Example]

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \newcounter{subfig}\setcounter{subfig}{0}
    \renewcommand\thesubfig{\textbf{\alph{subfig}}}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{overpic}[width=0.5\linewidth]{./bla}
            \put(10,10){\color{white}\stepcounter{subfig}\thesubfig}
        \end{overpic}%
        \begin{overpic}[width=0.5\linewidth]{./bla}
            \put(10,10){\color{white}\stepcounter{subfig}\thesubfig}
        \end{overpic}%
        \setcounter{subfig}{0}%
        \caption{\protect\stepcounter{subfig}\thesubfig{} Management of cultural differences, and \protect\stepcounter{subfig}\thesubfig{} Employees leaving.}
        \label{fig:employee leaving}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `[t]` on the `minipage` so they align on the images at the top rather than on the possibly varying caption.

If you do use `[b]` put `\label` *in* the caption not after it so that the `\write` node does not affect the bottom alignment.